# Single pharallax depending on mouse position. (without margins)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So i just saw this  `[http://jsfiddle.net/X7UwG/][1]`. So, when you move mouse to the left, everything is ok, but when you move mouse to the right there are white place. Is there any way not to have that. So just to do single pharallax effect without that white place (margins).

I want full width picture to just move a little depending on mouse position, as in example, but not to have that white place. Is that possible maybe with zooming image or somet

Answer (score 0):

Use percentages for the x-axis and scale the image to 110%

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/X7UwG/1411/)

```
$('#landing-content').mousemove(function(e){
    var amountMovedX = (( e.pageX / window.innerWidth ) * 100) ;
    var amountMovedY = (e.pageY * -1 / 6);
    $(this).css('background-position', amountMovedX + '% ' + amountMovedY + 'px');
});
```